# Bind Right Click on Qt aplication

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code which change the visibility of a point when i press key "U", i want to change the visibility(i changed "Qt::Key_u" with "Qt::RightClick") when i press "right click" but didn`t work.

```
  QShortcut *keyModifyVisibility = new QShortcut(this);
  keyModifyVisibility->setWhatsThis(tr("Modify current visibility"));
  keyModifyVisibility->setKey(Qt::Key_U);
  connect(keyModifyVisibility, SIGNAL(activated()), this, 
  SLOT(ModifyVisibility()));
```

Comment: You perform right click with a mouse button, and 'U' with a keyboard key - these are different actions. You cannot assign right click to a shortcut. If you want to handle mouse buttons clicks, you must use an alternative approach, such as handling mouse events.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code where you change the visibility of the 'point'.